# Reliable way to get the "ancestor" of an object with a specific classname, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a javascript function that gets called on change event of a select form element.  So, the "this" variable in js refers to the select element.

This select element is in a td tag, in a tr tag.  The tr tag has a classname of "FilterDetailsRow".

Now, I've tested, and if I use this syntax:

```
var filterRow = $(this).parent().parent();
```

it gets me what I want.  However, is there a better way to tell jQuery, "starting with "this" can you please go up my tree of parents until you find one with a classname of "FilterDetailsRow"?

Here's what I came up with, but I want to make sure I"m not reinventing the wheel.

```
function GetFilterDetailsRowOfObject(o) {
    if (o) {
        if (o.parent()[0].className.indexOf("FilterDetailsRow") != -1)
            return o;
        else
            return GetFilterDetailsRowOfObject(o.parent());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the first matching ancestor:

```
var filterRow = $(this).closest('.FilterDetailsRow');
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery 1.4 you can use [parentsUntil](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/).  For you it would be something like

```
$(this).parentsUntil('.FilterDetailsRow');
```

Comment: Not what the question is asking for. From the `parentsUntil` documentation: "Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, up to but not including the element matched by the selector."

Comment: closest() is best for this. Though, it starts with the current element (unlike parents() which starts with the first element), it will return zero or one object.

Comment: @Luke, ah, you're right.  To use this you'd have to go up one more level and then select the right parent out of the jQuery object returned.  Your answer works much more nicely.

Comment: So, are you saying to use this (I'll use Luke's answer, but just asking so I understand) I would probably want $(this).parentsUntil('.FilterDetailsRow').parent(); ?

Comment: @Matt, yes that is correct.  I thought it may be more complicated since parentsUntil returns all ancestors between your `this` and the selector passed to it, but after a quick test the code you proposed does work as expected.